# How to rule out that you have a faulty power supply?

Tags: arduino, power-supply, esp8266, troubleshooting

Just for context: I'm trying to code an ESP8266-ESP01 through an arduino, but I'm failing and my primary suspect, as per other forum issues I read, is that the power supply is the fault.

I've tried with 2 salvaged power supplies with way 3.2A and 2A vs the 0.2A peak that I need. [This regulator](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0159W0UL2) lowers voltage to 3.3V.
When connecting the board, voltmeter tells me that voltage drops to 3V or even 2.8V.

- In general, what tests can you do to a power supply to decide it's OK or faulty?
- Is it enough to see that voltage drops when they have load to say they are faulty?
- Are there any ripple or noise characteristics that could get in the way of my ESP8266 that I should measure?

Comment: Bad connection on the breadboard?

Comment: Are you using a scope? There certainly would be a point at which noise/ripple could interfere with things, but unless you have something you can measure it with, it would be hard to narrow that down as a suspect... When you say "a regulator lowers voltage to 3.3V" what regulator? Something you built? Purchased? Do you have information on that? What voltage do you start out at?

Comment: _"When connecting the board, voltmeter tells me that voltage drops to 3V or even 2.8V."_ - that's the regulator output voltage, right? What does the _input_ voltage do when this happens?

Comment: @StarCat, I've checked, but i don't have a way to guarantee that all connections are perfect. What would you do from there?

Comment: @RonBeyer yes, I have a scope; I see some ripple but how do I know it's too much? Every measurement is done in parallel with the regulator. I'll try measuring also between the power supply and the regulator. Added a link to the regulator I use. One power supply is at 12V and the other at 24V both have similar issues with lowering voltage from the regulator.

Comment: @BruceAbbot I'll try measuring also between the power supply and the regulator and let you know the results.

Comment: The answer to all three of your questions are: oscilloscope, oscilloscope and oscilloscope.

Comment: Your regulator should be plenty powerful enough _if_ it is adjusted correctly. Make sure the current limit is set high enough to draw at least 0.5A without the voltage dropping. It might also need a minimum load to stop the voltage from rising at low current, so if you set it with no load the voltage might drop under load.

Comment: @winny I have an oscilloscope, but don't know how to interpret it. I see ripple and noise and I understand too much of that will be an issue, but what is too much over a 3.3v signal? 10%? 5%? I still need to learn how to measure the ripple's amplitude, but I must be able to find that on my own :)

Comment: @Bruce Abbot as the regulator has an led display, I can "trust" the output voltage is set to 3.3v, but I don't know how to ensure that current is ok. Its also adjustable, but not visible from the led display

Comment: @Xavier Arias Botargues, you could check for a voltage drop between the output of the power supply and the power input of the ESP8266. If that causes the voltage drop it may be caused by a marginal connection somewhere in the path, possibly at one of the points of contact between the breadboard and the wiring. I've come across something like that once or twice.

Comment: Good! It depends on your application but 5 % would be a staring point for calculations. As you go lower and lower in voltage, what will fail first and at what level?

Comment: @StarCat answering your first message, yes, it was finally the breadboards fault :S